# Create fixture list from given teams

Tags: python, pandas

I've a list of teams as below:

```
|Team|
|---|
|A|
|B|
|C|
```

What would be the pandas/python way to create the following table of fixtures:

```
|Home Team|Away Team|
|---|---|
|A|B|
|A|C|
|B|A|
|B|C|
|C|A|
|C|B|
```

Each team plays the other team twice (home and away).

Comment: This so called cross join

Comment: Looks like cross join solved the question. Added one extra step to drop teams playing against themselves. ```all_fixtures = current_teams.assign(key=1).merge(current_teams.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', 1)
all_fixtures.drop(all_fixtures[all_fixtures['Team_x']==all_fixtures['Team_y']].index,inplace=True) ```

Comment: An alternative to `.merge` could be [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

Comment: `teams = ['A', 'B', 'C']`; 
`df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([teams, teams], names=['Home Team', 'Away Team']).to_frame(index=False)`; 
`df.drop(df.loc[df['Home Team'].eq(df['Away Team'])].index, inplace=True)`